# How can I flatten a list of floats in python without using numpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

```
[1.0, [1.0, [1.0, [0.25, [0.05, [0.01, [0.01, 0.01]]]]]]]
```

I am trying to flatten this list in python without using any modules not built into python 2. When I try to flatten it this error is raised:

```
 TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable on line 19
```

Comment: possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: Tried that- didn't work. Apparently floats are different and also I'm using Python 2. This question is not a duplicate... I have seen that thread and the method used there does not work for me.

Comment: Showing an error message is only helpful if we also see the code that it corresponds to. Otherwise the best we can tell you is that there is something wrong with the code, as described in the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion to flatten nested list:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            for v in flatten(i):
                yield v
        else:
            yield i

lst = [1.0, [1.0, [1.0, [0.25, [0.05, [0.01, [0.01, 0.01]]]]]]]

lst = list(flatten(lst))
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.25, 0.05, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, it worked

Comment: @HeapOverflow Yes, `yield from` was my first thought - but OP wants Python 2 solution, so I did it only with `yield`